# What's the difference between "Add to home screen" safari HTML5 webapp vs HTML5 webapp wrapped in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, html5

Someone asked me this. The answer he gave was HTML5 in `UIWebView` can cache the app data so it can run offline. I thought the same thing can be achieved using safari add to home screen, no?

Answer (score 1):

Safari "add to home screen" simply puts a bookmark to the webpage on the home screen - that's not the same as saving the page onto the phone. Because of memory limitations on mobile devices, Safari (and other mobile browsers) limit how much they cache. Adding a bookmakr to the home screen will not make a page available offline.

Creating your own app which displays your data with UIWebView means that you can configure your own caching scheme within your app. Or you can just include the HTML5 data within the app when the get it from the store. Either way, you control the offline ability of the app.

Comment: So html5 appcache doesn't work in iOS?

Comment: appcache does work - but it has limits, and is not as simple as "adding to home screen"